# subprocess.Popen command with quoted argument fails with shell=False

Tags: python, date, subprocess, metadata

I'm trying to change the creation date metadata of a file on macOS using python. The macOS shell command to do that is `SetFile -d '01/03/2012 12:00:00 PM' /path/to/file`.
I'm using the `subprocess` module to run a shell command in python, here is my code:

```
import subprocess

path = '/Users/marinnagy/Desktop/banner.jpg'
subprocess.Popen(['SetFile', '-d', '"01/03/2012 12:00:00 PM"', path])
```

No error occurs when running the script and the creation date of the file changes but to the wrong date. For this example, the date is changed to December 4th, 2011 (12/04/2011) instead of January 3st 2012. The shell command works well when used from the terminal, but the date is goes wrong when called from subprocess.

[Here](https://ss64.com/osx/setfile.html) is some information about the `SetFile` command, the date format is `mm/dd/[yy]yy [hh:mm:[:ss] [AM | PM]]`

Why is date wrong when using the command from subprocess, and how to fix it? Maybe I miss something, my computer is set to the french time format (dd/mm/yyyy) but doesn't seems to be linked.

Comment: You have both single-quoted and double-quoted the time. One should suffice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You've got too many quotes. The double quotes around the date format are only needed for the shell, so it doesn't split the argument at whitespace, and the shell strips off those quotes so `SetFile` doesn't see them.

If you were running with `shell=True`, passing a `str` instead of a `list`, you'd need them (e.g. `subprocess.Popen(f'SetFile -d "01/03/2012 12:00:00 PM" {shlex.quote(path)}', shell=True)`), but with the default `shell=False` (the correct way to use `subprocess`, being more efficient, stable, portable, and more secure against malicious input), you do the splitting yourself and the only quotes needed are those for Python string literals.

Since you're running without a shell, with a `list` of arguments, you've presplit the arguments already, and those interior double-quotes are passed verbatim, likely violating the expected format for your program.

Try just using:

```
subprocess.Popen(['SetFile', '-d', '01/03/2012 12:00:00 PM', path])
#                                   ^                    ^ double quotes removed
```